# jQuery Selectors: Which is faster for grabbing a subset of children?

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, jquery-selectors

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906076/jquery-selectors-grabbing-a-section-of-children-that-are-of-a-given-tag) question, I have the following 2 options:

```
$("tr td").slice(3, 6);
```

And possibly something like this (algorithmically speaking, I mean; I know making new query strings for each element is kinda silly):

```
var subset = $( "tr td:nth-child(4)" );
for(var i=4; i<7; i++) subset.add( "tr td:nth-child("+i+")" );
```

Which would perform more efficiently?  Would there be another more efficient solution?

Comment: I think someone would have to be a major contributor to jQuery to really be able to answer that without checking. Benchmark it?

Comment: It would seem to me that you would want a `>` child selector in there so jQuery is only looking for `<td>` elements that are a direct child of `<tr>`. `$("tr > td")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first (`$("tr td").slice(3, 6)`) would perform much faster, as it's a single selector engine call, but as always, test it!

I set up a performance test so you can check both (and other answers) yourself here: http://jsperf.com/slice-performance-test

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st code, you compute `$('tr td')` once and get a slice.

In the 2nd code, you compute `$('tr td')` 4 times, then extract the 4th to 7th child at each time.

Therefore the 1st code is faster. In fact, it is easier to read as well.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about algorithmic performance.  I guess I was assuming each query would get each element out as if simply referencing an element in an array.